# I can't believe it's not Replacement!

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, borel-sets, determinacy

(I feel like I might have to apologise in advance for this question, but oh well..)

I just rediscovered a [comment from Asaf K](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331392/how-much-replacement-does-this-axiom-provide#comment826483_331398) here on MO that states that full Replacement is not needed for Borel Determinacy (BD), a fact which flies in the face of everything I feel I've been led to believe. The [Wikipedia article on the set-theoretic niceties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem#Set-theoretic_aspects) is stated perfectly correctly, but a shallow reading might miss (as I did) the fact there's wriggle room between ZC (Zermelo with Choice), which is insufficient, and ZFC, which is sufficient. For a set theorist, the gap might be silly, but not when it comes to models.

*Some* Replacement is needed, but not unboundedly-large instances, it seems. Asaf says that it only requires that $\beth_{\omega_1}$ exists. So is this my question: for which $V_\alpha$ does BD hold? Is it just those ordinals $\alpha$ so that $\beth_{\omega_1} \in V_\alpha$? Or is there a different characterisation? How about models of the form $H_\alpha$? Then one gets models of some set theory that is stronger than ZC, but weaker than ZFC, in which BD holds. Such information would be good to add to WP, for instance, but also to draw the sort of fine line that Reverse Mathematicians like to see.

---

As Noah points out in the comments, I'm making a bit of a muddle here. But I think what I want to know is how much replacement over ZC does one actually need to prove BD. François indicates that something like Replacement for functions with countable domain is sufficient, but not tight. I would be willing to countenance arguments of the sort that justify Dependent Choice in an otherwise choice-free setting, in order to extrinsically justify countable Replacement aside from knowing it proves BD.

Comment: BD holds in all $V_\alpha$ in which all relevant parameters exist: so $\alpha \geq \omega+5$ is enough for most encodings and $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is more than enough for everyone who is not deliberately acting silly. Similar (but slightly different) situation for the $H$ hierarchy are true. This is because these are defined in ZFC and $\beth_{\omega_1}$ does exist; these are not predicative definitions!

Comment: Seriously though, the language you're looking for is $n$-th order arithmetic, often denoted $Z_n$ (but I personally think this historical notation should be revised).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I see what you are saying, but $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is the poster child of models of BZC (say), and I was led to believe this is not enough to prove BD! Maybe I don't mean models, but I'm trying to get a handle on exactly how to describe the set theory that has BD, partly by looking at models where it does that aren't models of ZFC.

Comment: What is necessary over ZC is basically countable replacement, which is enough to get $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$. (That takes more work than you might think!) But you only need the instances of countable replacement used in the proof of BD, though.

Comment: Hmm, that makes this even less clear! Weasel words (sorry!) like "basically" are what contribute to the hazy picture, in my head,at least. But if Replacement in the sense of having a function from a countable set is all that's needed, that's awesome!

Comment: Sorry for the wording, countable replacement is enough but it's a bit too much for reasons I explained. (Though the "too much" part is mostly visible in combination with other axioms.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais ah, ok. That a nice upper bound, at least. It's a bit like having DC or countable choice, in that there is probably an argument that give a level of justification not available for the an unrestricted axiom.

Comment: @DavidRoberts There's an odd mix-up in this question between theories and structures here. The $V_{\omega+\omega}$ (for example) of any model $V\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ will satisfy BD, since BD is essentially just a statement about reals. But this has nothing to do with the amount of replacement needed for BD. Basically, "Which $V_\alpha$s (or similar) satisfy BD?" is just not the right question to ask.

Comment: That's exactly right: BD is a fixed target so general axioms are too general for that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, thanks. And apologies for the mix-up. Hopefully people can see through my misunderstanding to what I'm hinting at, and what [François' comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395430/i-cant-believe-its-not-replacement?noredirect=1#comment1012177_395430) seems to answer.

Comment: I believe it is not so much replacement that is needed, but rather existence of suitably large power iterated power sets that is. A reasonably precise statement of strength is given in Theorem 1.1 [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~shac/Calibrating.pdf) - over set theory without power set, existence of $P^\alpha(\omega)$ is sufficient for $\Sigma^0_{1+\alpha+2}$-determinacy, but not $\Sigma^0_{1+\alpha+3}$ determinacy, at least in the presence of $\Sigma_1$-replacement. I'm not sure to what extent this answers your question.

Comment: Also, although this may be a slightly silly point, it should not at all be surprising that BD doesn't require full replacement - BD is a single formula in the lanuage of ZFC, so it can't depend on an entire axiom schema.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for the comments. I should have realised that no theorem of ZFC requires more than finitely many instances of Replacement! Someone else pointed my to Don Martin's book on Determinacy, and I see rather precise statements of the form you outline. In particular, he notes that $\Sigma_1$ replacement can be removed, at the cost of using different sets for ordinals (as opposed to von Neumann ordinals), and then $\alpha$-iterated power sets for all countable $\alpha$ is enough for BD.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise discussion in the comments, particularly [from Wojowu](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395430/i-cant-believe-its-not-replacement#comment1012247_395430), the answer I was after is in Tony Martin's book, *Determinacy of infinitely long games* ([author's draft pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Edam/booketc/D.A._Martin,_Determinacy_of_Infinitely_Long_Games.pdf)). At the cost of assuming $\Sigma_1$ Replacement, so that some standard constructions work (I think von Neumann ordinals and cartesian products), what is really needed is the existence of the power set $P^\alpha(\omega)$, for all countable ordinals $\alpha$. Replacement using functions on countable sets is sufficient (and, intriguingly, something Zermelo more-or-less considered as an axiom, in the 1920s). Without $\Sigma_1$ Replacement, it will still work (noted by Martin), but one must use different models for the ordinals, for instance.

But there is a much more nuanced post and discussion in the blog post by Tom Leinster, *[Borel Determinacy Does Not Require Replacement](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2021/07/borel_determinacy_does_not_require_replacement.html)*, the title of which is, I think, deliberately provocative.